# Why is a random variable on a sigma algebra not necessarily measurable on a sub sigma algebra?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, analysis, measure-theory, conditional-expectation

I have a question regarding the following bolded claim made on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation)

Consider the following:

- $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ is a probability space.
- $X: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is a random variable on that probability space with finite expectation.
- $\mathcal{H} \subseteq \mathcal{F}$ is a sub-\sigma-algebra of $\mathcal{F}$.

**Since $\mathcal{H}$ is a sub $\sigma$-algebra of $\mathcal{F}$, the function $X: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is usually not $\mathcal{H}$-measurable**, thus the existence of the integrals of the form $\left.\int_{H} X d P\right|_{\mathcal{H}}$, where $H \in \mathcal{H}$ and $\left.P\right|_{\mathcal{H}}$ is the restriction of $P$ to $\mathcal{H}$, cannot be stated in general. However, the local averages $\int_{H} X d P$ can be recovered in $\left(\Omega, \mathcal{H},\left.P\right|_{\mathcal{H}}\right)$ with the help of the conditional expectation. A conditional expectation of $X$ given $\mathcal{H}$, denoted as $\mathrm{E}(X \mid \mathcal{H})$, is any $\mathcal{H}$ measurable function $\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}$ which satisfies:
$$
\int_{H} \mathrm{E}(X \mid \mathcal{H}) \mathrm{d} P=\int_{H} X \mathrm{~d} P
$$

Why is a random variable on a sigma algebra not necessarily measurable on a sub sigma algebra? If a sub-sigma algebra is a collection of subsets from the original sigma algebra which forms a sigma algebra in its own right, why wouldn't this enable any random variable to continue to be measurable on some sub-sigma algebra?

Comment: Consider the case $\mathcal{H} = \{\emptyset , \Omega \}$. Which functions are measurable here?

Comment: @JoseAvilez Would it only be only bernoulli random variables?

Comment: No. Only constants would be measurable.

Comment: @JoseAvilez So since this is a sub-sigma algebra of every sigma algbera on Omega,  this is a counter example?

Comment: It's an example that exhibits why an $\mathcal{F}$-random variable need not be measurable with respect to $\mathcal{H}$. If $X$ is any non-constant random variable that is $\mathcal{F}$-measurable, it cannot be $\mathcal{H}$-measurable.

Comment: @JoseAvilez So we can still integrate the random variable $X$ on subsets in $\mathcal{H}$ but $X$ just might not be $\mathcal{H}$  measurable? What is the benefit of having a random variable which is $\mathcal{H}$-measurable if the expectations on these subsets are already defined and the integrals between $X$ and the conditional expectation of $X$ on $H$ are the same?

Comment: You may not integrate $X$ when viewed as a function from $(\Omega , \mathcal{H})$ because it is not measurable. This is the entire point of conditional expectations: to find a random variable which you *can* integrate which is $\mathcal{H}$-measurable.

Comment: @JoseAvilez Then how is this integral $\int_{H} \mathrm{E}(X \mid \mathcal{H}) \mathrm{d} P=\int_{H} X \mathrm{~d} P$ defined if $f$ is not $\mathcal{H}$ measurable?

Comment: The integral on the left treats $E(X | \mathcal{H})$ as an $\mathcal{H}$-random variable. The integral on the right treats $X$ as a $\mathcal{F}$-random variable.

Comment: @JoseAvilez I see does the expected value of the random variable $E(X|\mathcal{H})$ differ from $X$ on any subsets? It seems like these would end up being the same since we are only considering a sub sigma algebra of $\mathcal{F}$ on the LHS.

Comment: Yes. Take the following example. Let $\Omega = [0,1]$ with Lebesgue measure and $\mathcal{F}$ the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of $[0,1]$. Now set $\mathcal{G} = \{ \emptyset , \Omega , [0,0.5), [0.5,1] \}$. Let $X(\omega) = \omega$. Can you compute $E(X|\mathcal{G})$?

Comment: @JoseAvilez Well, I know what the lebesgue integral works out to be on the subsets of $\mathcal{G}$, its just the riemann integral of $x$ with bounds being the endpoints of the sets.  So I need some $\mathcal{G}$-measurable function. But what would the measure be on $\mathcal{G}$? Would I continue to use the lebesgue-measure restricted to subsets of $\mathcal{G}$? There must be some formula to commpute this because otherwise, I would have to conjecture the right function to use

Comment: $E(X | \mathcal{G})$ doesn't have a measure, it's a function. The measure of the sets in $\mathcal{G}$ is their usual Lebesgue measure.

Comment: @JoseAvilez I'm thinking $\mathcal{G}$ would be some sort of step function. On the $[0,1/2)$ the function is $1$ and on $[1/2,1]$ the function is $3/4$? Then the integrals would work out to be the same on these intervals while $\mathcal{G}$ is still measurable.

Comment: Almost! This sequence of comments was getting a bit long, so I've posted an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sequence of comments above was getting a bit long, so I'll convert it into an answer.

As noted in @William's answer, making the domain's $\sigma$-algebra smaller while keeping the co-domain's $\sigma$-algebra fixed makes it harder for a function to be measurable.

As an example, if we take any non-constant random variable $X$ on a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{F}$, and then set $\mathcal{G} = \{\emptyset, \Omega\} \subset \mathcal{F}$, then we note that $X$ cannot be measurable, as only constants are $\mathcal{G}$-measurable.

As an example for computing a conditional expectation, set $\Omega = [0,1]$, $\mathcal{F} = \mathcal{B}[0,1]$, and $P = \lambda$ (Lebesgue measure). We now set $\mathcal{G} = \{\emptyset , [0,1], [0,0.5), [0.5, 1]\}$ and relativise $\lambda$ to $\mathcal{G}$ (i.e. we assign Lebesgue measure to the sets in $\mathcal{G}$). Consider the random variable $X : \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $X(\omega ) = \omega$. This is $\mathcal{F}$-measurable, but it is not $\mathcal{G}$-measurable.

Notice that $\int_{[0,0.5)} X dP = \frac{1}{8}$ and $\int_{[0.5, 1]} X dP = \frac{3}{8}$. We now wish to find a $\mathcal{G}$-measurable function that integrates to these same values. For a function to be $\mathcal{G}$-measurable, it must be constant on $[0,0.5)$ and $[0.5,1]$. Thus, we may set $$Y(\omega) = \begin{cases}
\frac{1}{4} & 0 \leq \omega < 0.5 \\
\frac{3}{4} & 0.5 \leq \omega \leq 1
\end{cases}$$
Notice that $Y$ is $\mathcal{G}$-measurable and $\int_{[0,0.5)} Y dP = \frac{1}{8}$ and $\int_{[0.5, 1]} Y dP = \frac{3}{8}$. Thus $E(X | \mathcal{G}) = Y$.

Comment: Thank you for your many comments and very instructive guidance! This helps so much for preparing for my seminar course which uses conditional expectation as assumed knowledge

Comment: @SamKirkiles Pleasure! Good luck on your seminar course.

Answer (score 1):

A function $f : (X_1,\Sigma_1,\mu_1) \to (X_2,\Sigma_2,\mu_2)$ is $(\Sigma_1,\Sigma_2)$-measurable if for all $M \in \Sigma_2$, it holds that $f^{-1}(M) \in \Sigma_1$.

If $S \subset \Sigma_1$, it may hold that $f^{-1}(M)$ is not in it, which is the technical statement of the bolded text.

As a general example, suppose that $f$ is $(\Sigma_1,\Sigma_2)$-measurable, and $\varnothing \neq M \subsetneq X_2$ so that $M \in \Sigma_2$. If $S$ is any $\sigma$-subalgebra of $\Sigma_1$ which does not contain $f^{-1}(S)$, then $f$ is not $(S,\Sigma_2)$-measurable.

As a concrete example, if the trivial $\sigma$-algebra $\{\varnothing,X_1\}$ is $T$, then any nonconstant which is $(\Sigma_1,\Sigma_2)$-measurable ($\Sigma_1 \neq T$) is not $(T,\Sigma_2)$-measurable.

---

A high-level takeaway of this fact is that although the codomain's $\sigma$-algebra plays a vital role in measurability, it is the domain's $\sigma$-algebra that can "make it hard" to be measurable. Indeed, see that for a fixed codomain with a fixed $\sigma$-algebra, the fewer sets in the domain's $\sigma$-algebra, the harder it is for a function between those spaces to be measurable with respect to those $\sigma$-algebras.

Comment: If someone were to say to compute the conditional expected value with respect to some set, would this mean to produce a random variable? Or to produce the expected value of that random variable?